# Geom_tile plots non-existent discontinuities in data for time axis

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, heatmap, geom-tile

If I have the following dataframe called data

```
year    month   id  group   returns
2016    2   asset_a group1  0.11592118
2016    3   asset_a group1  0.104526128
2016    4   asset_a group1  0.244925532
2016    5   asset_a group1  0.252377372
2016    6   asset_a group1  0.282602889
2016    7   asset_a group1  0.607148925
2016    8   asset_a group1  0.257815581
2016    9   asset_a group1  0.202712468
2016    10  asset_a group1  0.177455704
2016    11  asset_a group1  0.208526305
2016    12  asset_a group1  0.179808043
2017    1   asset_a group1  0.204425208
2017    2   asset_a group1  0.167787787
2017    3   asset_a group1  0.122357671
2017    4   asset_a group1  0.095889965
2017    5   asset_a group1  0.180117687
2017    6   asset_a group1  0.146912234
2017    7   asset_a group1  0.286743829
2017    8   asset_a group1  0.201531197
2017    9   asset_a group1  0.166819132
2017    10  asset_a group1  0.136262625
2017    11  asset_a group1  0.128844762
2017    12  asset_a group1  0.147595906
2018    1   asset_a group1  0.099843877
2018    2   asset_a group1  0.1928918
2018    3   asset_a group1  0.188344307
2018    4   asset_a group1  0.155801889
2018    5   asset_a group1  0.185813076
2018    6   asset_a group1  0.217531263
2018    7   asset_a group1  0.269840901
2018    8   asset_a group1  0.267351364
2018    9   asset_a group1  0.183753448
2018    10  asset_a group1  0.195182592
2018    11  asset_a group1  0.228886115
2018    12  asset_a group1  0.166964407
```

and in order to plot it in a heatmap I create a date vector with

```
data <- data %>%
 mutate(date= make_datetime(year, month))
```

I get a database structure of

```
 $ year     : int [1:564] 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 ...
 $ month    : int [1:564] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ id       : chr [1:564] "asset_a" "asset_b" "asset_c" "asset_d" ...
 $ group    : chr [1:564] "group1" "group2" "group3" "group4" ...
 $ returns  : num [1:564] 0.115 0.3 0.105 0.245 0.28 ...
 $ date     : POSIXct[1:564], format: "2016-02-01" "2016-02-01" "2016-02-01" "2016-02-01" ...
```

and inputting that into the ggplot heatmap

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = asset))  + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = returns)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#66bf7b", "#a1d07e", "#dce182", 
                                 "#ffeb84",
                                 "#fedb81", "#faa075", "#faa075"),
                       values=rescale(c(-3, -2, -1,
                                        0,
                                        1, 2, 3)),
                       guide="colorbar") +
 
  labs(x="",y="")
```

I get

[image]

**Why did the ggplot create missing data out of nowhere, given that my data in the dataframe is without any monthly discontinuities?** How can I fix it so that there are no white gaps in between the dates, is it related to hours and seconds in the date format?

If I plot the dates as characters I get the desired result, however, in that case, how can I reduce the number of ticks on the date axis to be readable?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
The output according to stefan's suggestion didn't solve it because each asset id should have its own heatmap row. Right now, they are plotted on top of each other.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

For me this didn't work

```
breaks <- sort(unique(as.numeric(factor(data$id)))) - .5
labels <- levels(factor(data$id))
```

Typing out manually:

```
  mutate(xmin = date,
         xmax = date + months(1),
         ymin = case_when(
               id == "asset_a" ~ 0,
               id == "asset_b" ~ 1,
               id == "asset_c" ~ 2,
               id == "asset_d" ~ 3,
               id == "asset_e" ~ 4,
               id == "asset_f" ~ 5,
               id == "asset_g" ~ 6,
               id == "asset_h" ~ 7,
               id == "asset_i" ~ 8,
         ),
         ymax = case_when(
               id == "asset_a" ~ 1,
               id == "asset_b" ~ 2,
               id == "asset_c" ~ 3,
               id == "asset_d" ~ 4,
               id == "asset_e" ~ 5,
               id == "asset_f" ~ 6,
               id == "asset_g" ~ 7,
               id == "asset_h" ~ 8,
               id == "asset_i" ~ 9)
  )
```

solved the problem and each asset id is stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what's the issue but my guess is that `geom_tile` chooses the same width and height for each tile. However, because months differ in the number of days you get the discontinuities.

One option to achieve your desired result while still making use of a date or date time would be to switch to `geom_rect` which however needs some additional steps to compute the coordinates of the four corners:

**EDIT** To make the example more in line with your real data I added a two more assets where I simply replicated your example data but added some random noise to the returns. I also fixed a bug in my original code which resulted in wrong axis labels as I missed to sort the values when computing the breaks.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

set.seed(123)

data2 <- data
data2$id <- "asset_b"
data2$returns <- data2$returns + runif(nrow(data2), 0, .2)

data3 <- data
data3$id <- "asset_c"
data3$returns <- data3$returns + runif(nrow(data3), 0, .2)
data <- bind_rows(data2, data, data3)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(date = make_datetime(year, month),
         xmin = date,
         xmax = date + months(1),
         ymin = as.numeric(factor(id)) - 1,
         ymax = as.numeric(factor(id)))

breaks <- sort(unique(as.numeric(factor(data$id)))) - .5
labels <- levels(factor(data$id))

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date))  + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = returns)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#66bf7b", "#a1d07e", "#dce182", 
                                 "#ffeb84",
                                 "#fedb81", "#faa075", "#faa075"),
                       values=rescale(c(-3, -2, -1,
                                        0,
                                        1, 2, 3)),
                       guide="colorbar") +
  
  labs(x="",y="")
```

[image]

Another option to get your desired result would be to convert your date column to a character as you already suggested in your post. Here we have to do some data wrangling to set up the axis breaks, labels and limits to mimic the date axis:

```r
data <- data %>%
  mutate(date = make_datetime(year, month))

limits <- expand.grid(
  year = 2016:2018, 
  month = 1:12
) %>% 
  add_row(year = 2019, month = 1) %>% 
  mutate(date = make_datetime(year, month)) %>% 
  pull(date) %>% 
  sort()
breaks <- make_datetime(2016:2019, 1)

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.character(date), y = id))  + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = returns)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = as.character(breaks), labels = year(breaks), limits = as.character(limits)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#66bf7b", "#a1d07e", "#dce182", 
                                 "#ffeb84",
                                 "#fedb81", "#faa075", "#faa075"),
                       values=rescale(c(-3, -2, -1,
                                        0,
                                        1, 2, 3)),
                       guide="colorbar") +
  
  labs(x="",y="")
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
structure(list(year = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L), month = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), id = c("asset_a", 
"asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", 
"asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", 
"asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", 
"asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", 
"asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", 
"asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a", "asset_a"), group = c("group1", 
"group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1"), 
    returns = c(0.11592118, 0.104526128, 0.244925532, 0.252377372, 
    0.282602889, 0.607148925, 0.257815581, 0.202712468, 0.177455704, 
    0.208526305, 0.179808043, 0.204425208, 0.167787787, 0.122357671, 
    0.095889965, 0.180117687, 0.146912234, 0.286743829, 0.201531197, 
    0.166819132, 0.136262625, 0.128844762, 0.147595906, 0.099843877, 
    0.1928918, 0.188344307, 0.155801889, 0.185813076, 0.217531263, 
    0.269840901, 0.267351364, 0.183753448, 0.195182592, 0.228886115, 
    0.166964407)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L
))
```

Comment: please see my edit. I tried your solution but it didn't solve it. Is there another way to align the days of the month so that there won't be any white spaces? Why doesn't it do it for simple line chart?

Comment: Hm. I just made an edit to include a second asset and fixed a bug. As far as I get it, at least for the data I used the code works fine. So not sure what's the issue when applied to your real data. But I added a second option based on converting your date column to a character.

Comment: for me `breaks <- sort(unique(as.numeric(factor(data$id)))) - .5` and `labels <- levels(factor(data$id))` didn't work. I manually typed out the list and it stacked it properly.  I have to revisit this with a fresh go